# Spring Cloud Turbine Amqp doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

I have a problem with spring cloud:  Turbine Amqp doesn't work. I exploit a local rabbit broker out of the box.

one of my services:

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.sample")
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
```

dependencies:

```
spring-cloud-config-client
spring-cloud-starter-eureka
spring-cloud-starter-feign
spring-boot-starter-actuator
spring-cloud-starter-hystrix
spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp
spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp
```

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
     host: 127.0.0.1
     port: 5672
```

my turbine service:

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableTurbineAmqp
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication

spring-cloud-config-client
spring-cloud-starter-eureka
spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp
spring-cloud-starter-turbine-amqp
spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard

spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 5672

turbine:
  amqp:
  port: 8989

management:
  port: 8090
```

when i try to execute http://127.0.0.1:8989/turbine.stream, i've got:
data: {"type":"Ping"} in cycle

rabbitmqctl list_queues - shows a new queue ...f1d5cfa119f5 0  at the same time when my "client" service is executed. when i turn it off the queue is removed.

turbine server writes:

```
SSE Request Received
Unsubscribing RxNetty server connection
```

What am i doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: What versions of spring-cloud are you using? Have you exercised the circuit breaker?

Comment: 1.  <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Angel.SR6</version>


2.   i use the feign client to access to other services, i thought it had used  the circuit breaker inside. I don't know this topic well, maybe i just don't understand something

Comment: In angel it doesn't, that's a new feature in Brixton. Based on what you've described, ping... is all you get because you have no circuit breakers.